# Trigger VNext Build with VNext Build

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, build, continuous-integration, tfs-2015

We used to run XAML Builds, there you could start one Build from another, for example let a GC run an Integration Test workflow afterwards and so on.

In VNext there is no way to trigger other Buils.
How can we make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Feature is under plan, but don't have yet.

Check [this User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2165043-provide-build-configuration-dependencies-in-tfs-bu), and the QA on [this website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#can-i-chain-builds-so-that-one-build-triggers-another-):

**Can I chain builds so that one build triggers another?**

Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell for that task: [more information](https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2016/05/03/visual-studio-team-services-triggering-a-build-from-a-build-using-powershell/)